# What is a controller's change event in angular ? is it same as $watch a model?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out an angular [module](https://github.com/fmaturel/angular-weekly-scheduler)(This question isn't specific the module i'm studying but just about an angular specific syntax which i didn't understand what) and inside its main directive, the controller was passed to the link function and then a change event listener was hooked to it :

```
schedulerCtrl.on = {
      change: function (itemIndex, scheduleIndex, scheduleValue) {
           var onChangeFunction = $parse(attrs.onChange)(scope);
           if (angular.isFunction(onChangeFunction)) {
                return onChangeFunction(itemIndex, scheduleIndex, scheduleValue);
           }
      }
};
```

(this chuck of code exists in the [ng-weekly-scheduler.js file](https://github.com/fmaturel/angular-weekly-scheduler/blob/master/dist/js/ng-weekly-scheduler.js) at line 362.)

The `attrs.onChange` is gotten from the directive declaration in html which looks like this :

```
<weekly-scheduler class="scheduler" items="model.items" on-change="demo.doSomething" on-delete="demo.doSomething" options="model.options">
      <div class="srow">{{::$index + 1}}. {{item.label}}</div>
</weekly-scheduler>
```

I have never heard about setting an event listener to an angular controller. So please ,anyone can tell me what does it means and to which part of the angular API is it related ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`weekly-scheduler` is a third party directive which you get when you inject the required module (I think its `weeklyScheduler`). So now you have the scheduler control displayed in your page. Now, say you want to perform some logic when the something changes inside the scheduler - like, you want to create/update a new event and save it to database - for this, you gotta get a call back with the required values from the scheduler to your controller method.

This is were `&` binding of directives are used - `&` binding is for passing a method into your directive's scope so that it can be called within your directive. So in your case, you bind `doSomething` method to the `onChangeFunction (exposed as onChange)` binding of the directive which is in-turn called when some model changes happen inside the scheduler - `return onChangeFunction(itemIndex, scheduleIndex, scheduleValue);` - So in your controller method, you will get `itemIndex`, `scheduleIndex` and `scheduleValue` related to the change happened.

More details here - https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-am

> The “&” operator allows you to invoke or evaluate an expression on the
>   parent scope of whatever the directive is inside of.

Comment: Thanks, i still don't understand how a listener could be attached to the controller's oject (instance), i think it's a jquery listener and usually it should be attached to the element we want to listen to changes in. It was strange for me that a listener hooked on the controller would be sensible to a DOM event. What if there were other elements on the DOM emitting change events , how the listener .on('change' would know  from which element it comes from

Comment: Not sure whether I got your question correct. Consider that you are writing a custom directive which would inject 5 dropdowns in your page. And as per your design, you would like to give a callback to controller whenever the 3rd dropdown value is changed - so you will have a `&` binding for that exposed for which you assign a controller method. Inside the directive, you would listen to the model change/change event of the third dropdown and inside that you will trigger the call back method.

Comment: I mean to say that the `schedulerCtrl.on.change` method will not be called on change method of every elements. It is configured inside the directive when to trigger the callback method. Check out line 551 in that js file.

Comment: If you analyse the given code, the `schedulerCtrl.on.change` in line 551 is called whenever there is a change in the model - and the model is changed when you do something in the scheduler.

Comment: my question was about what you called " giving a callback to controller" by attaching an event listener to it. I never saw any example alike but let's say the controller instance is itself an object like others. Now, what makes that listener to be sensible to a change which occured in the directive? is it just obvious ?

Comment: @Bardelman - May be I'm too bad in explaining things :). Check out this fiddle I created - https://plnkr.co/edit/b49Psh2pZ2UAzkZBt1KE?p=preview and let me know your thoughts

Comment: @Developper No! you are really great ! thank you so much!! it seems i'm the one bad with asking, i understood that the “&” operator allows evaluating an expression but i just still can't understand why it was obvious that the listener attached to the controller with .on('change'.. was able to detect the change in the directive. If it was attached to the link's "element" argument instead for me it would be more natural But really thank you again for your efforts.

Comment: I think you got confused with jQuery `.on()` with the `schedulerCtrl.on.change` method. Here `.on` is just an object which has a method named `change`, no way related to binding of change event related to whole controller. Consider as a custom class - `var myCustomObject = function (){ this.on = { change: function (){} } }` and you call it as `var custom = new myCustomObject(); custom.on.change ()`

Comment: Well, yes i was thinking it could be so as you said but i still have to understand why it triggers once the change happens (as it turns out that  it's not a real listener anymore now, just a method). I will consider your answer as correct then because you deserve it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the directive, and indeed the wording here can be confusing...

Actually, this portion of code:

```
schedulerCtrl.on = {
      change: function (itemIndex, scheduleIndex, scheduleValue) {
      ...
      }
};
```

is **not** using a built-in angularJS mechanism to set an event listener in the controller. Angular has `$on` listeners on **scopes** but that is a different feature.

The code is just referencing a function called `change` on an object `schedulerCtrl.on` (`on` could bee renamed to `foo`... it does not matter. This, indeed, may be confusing, especially if already used JQuery).

The `change` method is explicitly called afterwards (Line 546) when a change is triggered by an ng-model change (Here, `$parsers` is a built-in behaviour of [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)). Note the prefix `$` of `$parsers`, `$watcher`, `$on`... on angular api internal objects or api.

```
//// UI -> model ////////////////////////////////////
ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function onUIChange(ui) {
    ...
    schedulerCtrl.on.change(index, scope.$index, ngModelCtrl.$modelValue);
    ....
});
```

In brief:

- `schedulerCtrl` has a property `on` which is a simple JS object (not used by angular) referencing a `change` function.
- This `change` is called by built-in ngModelController `ngModelCtrl` when a change is detected on the model (for instance when user slides the time bars)

Comment: yes indeed it was a bit confusing for me as both the syntax and behaviour are too similar to an event listener.. i also continued reading the code and reached the part in which that function was called and everything is clear now. Thanks!